# Adding class to last list item? Not WP generated

Tags: plugins, custom-field, functions, list, advanced-custom-fields

this one has been getting me for a while. At the moment I have a repeater field with Advanced Custom Fields:

```
<ul id="servicelist" class="clearfix">
<?php if(get_field('homepage_service')): ?>
        <?php while(the_repeater_field('homepage_service')): ?>
            <li><img src="<?php the_sub_field('service_image'); ?>" />
        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is apply a class to the last item generated by this... is there a way (or a function) to give a class to every last list item on a WP site?

Thanks

Comment: Woah there - tame that unclosed `<li>`! Would selecting `#servicelist li:last-child` not be easier?

Comment: Easier, in a way, yes - but if I can get it done via PHP then I won't have to worry about browser compatibility

Answer (score 2):

I can only see achieving this by first building an array, then looping over it - I can't find anything in APC's docs about checking if it's the last iteration of `the_repeater_field`:

```
$images = array();
while ( the_repeater_field( 'homepage_service' ) )
    $images[] = get_sub_field( 'service_image' );

if ( $images ) {
    $image_last = array_pop( $images );

    echo '<ul id="servicelist" class="clearfix">';
    if ( $images )  
        echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $images ) . '</li>';
    echo '<li class="last-child">' . $image_last . '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
```